# Different P-Values from F test and anova

Tags: r, anova, f-test

I would like to compare two Groups.

My null hypothese $H_0$:  two groups are same

alternative hypothese $H_a$: these two groups are different

I use `anova` and `F-Test` in R. but the result of P-Value of `anova` and `F-Test` are totaly different. one of them accept the $H_0$ and the another one reject it.

here is my code:

```
#Anova test
Group1<-c(2,3,7,2,6)
Group2<-c(10,8,7,5,10)
combined_Groups <- data.frame(cbind(Group1,Group2))
staked_Group<-stack(combined_Groups)
Anova_Result<-aov(values ~ ind,data=staked_Group)
summary(Anova_Result)
# Result of anova
#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
# ind          1     40      40       8 0.0222 *
# Residuals    8     40       5                 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#F-Test
var.test(Group1,Group2)
#Result of F-test

#   F test to compare two variances

# data:  Group1 and Group2
# F = 1.2222, num df = 4, denom df = 4, p-value = 0.8505
# alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.1272548 11.7388699
# sample estimates:
# ratio of variances 
#          1.222222
```

could some one explin me why `P-values` totaly different and which one is correct one in my case?

Comment: One of them is comparing the group means the other is comparing the group variances. Which one is correct depends on your scientific hypothesis.

Comment: Your hypothesis should be about the populations from which the groups were drawn. Are you proposing to test the hypothesis that they have the same mean against the alternative that the means differ?

Comment: @Glen_b I want to measure the similarity of these groups, and I have no idea what should I measure. my hypothese may be more correct when I say. Group1 and Group2 are similar and alternative hypothese Group1 and Group2 are not similar

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "similarity"? It's not defined well enough to be a null hypothesis -- indeed that doesn't even sound like you should be doing a hypothesis test at all.

Comment: It is exactly one of my problem. I should measure similarity between groups, but I dont know exactly on which base? What I thought was Variance. What do you mean?is it a correct measure? do you have another idea?

Comment: There are many things you *might* mean by "similarity". If you mean "tend to take similar values" then you *might* look at defining similarity by some measure of difference in location (such as a statistic that picks up deviations in means or medians or any number of other measures). Or you might talk about the differences in the distribution as a whole (in which case various multi-sample goodness of fit measures might be closer to what you need). I can't tell you what you mean by "similar". But *measuring* similarity doesn't suggest a test at all...

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you so much for your hints. I have decided to test the distribution of data in two sets  with ks.test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are **not** valid hypothesis:

> My null hypothese $H_0$: two groups are same
>
> alternative hypothese $H_a$: these two groups are different

"The same" in what sense? Exactly the same in every aspect?

```
all(Group1 == Group2)
## [1] FALSE
```

...they are not *exactly* the same. You should state your hypothesis more precisely.

You conducted two hypothesis tests: [$F$-test of equality of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances) and  [$F$-test for ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance); in the first case you tested if both groups have the same *variances*, in the second case you tested if they have the same *means*. There are four possible combinations of those two features:

1. same means, same variances,
2. same means, different variances,
3. different means, same variances,
4. different means, different variances,

and there is no reason to believe why same means should correspond to same variances (unless you are talking about distributions like Poisson, but this is a different story).

As a sidenote: why are you using ANOVA rather then a [$t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test) while you are comparing two groups?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have used a bad word! I don't like to determine if these two group are same, otherwise i would like to measure the SIMILARITY between these two groups (actually I would like to do it for three groups, and then determine which two groups are similar to each other). I am not using a t test becuase these groups are almost big with 3000 values and the have differnet length. How do you find: Is it a good idea to use F-test for measuring the similarity of groups?

Comment: @Kaja What kind of similarity? This seems to be a different question.

Comment: Actually I have no measure. I got three groups of integer values and I want to measure the similarity. Unfortuanatly I have no more infos. I thought may be measure variance with hypothese helps to measure the somilarity . Do you have any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: @Kaja I'm afraid that unless you make it more precise what do you mean by "similarity", the question is unanswerable and *you* won't be able to get any meaningful results of your analysis.

Comment: How would you define similarity for two groups of integer values with different length. Mean? Variance? or something else?

Comment: @Kaja as I said, unless you know what you want to achieve, the discussion is pointless. You can define similarity as e.g. proportion of 0's in your data, as proportion of odd  vs even numbers, in terms of multiple different statistics etc. etc., basically there is unlimited number of similarities and dissimilarities. This is problem-specific and the fact that your data is integer-valued does not make much difference in here.

Comment: Last question: Is it totaly meaningless to measure the Variance by F test?

Comment: @Kaja it is not meaningless if you want to test hypothesis if two variances are equal and if your two variables are normally distributed, since the test can be sensitive to non-normality.

Comment: @Tim Good try!  I think you have done all you can!  Any more  dialogue between you and the OP just further opens Pandora's box.

Comment: @Kaja 1. Are you sure you really want a *test*, rather than just some sense of how different they are? 2. Are you trying to look for any differences in distribution rather than just mean and variance?